# Adding a manufacturer to a virtual product?

Tags: magento-1.8, virtual-products

I noticed that the options for manufacturer disappears for downloadable and virtual products. Is there anyway to change the code to override this restriction in magento 1.8.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you just need to edit the Manufacturer attribute from admin side and assign the virtual product and downloadable product type to the product.

For e.g if you wants to assign manufacturer to virtual product, To do this follow the below steps:

1) login to admin panel

2) From the Top navigation select "Manage Attributes" from Catalog>>Attributes>>Manage Attributes.

3) Find manufacturer from the list and edit it

4) Select the virtual product from the apply to multiselct box, see the screen shot.

[image]

5) Save the attributes

6) Now it will be available to select manufacturer for virtual product